# display records one by one by storing it in a variable

Tags: tcl

I have a select query(the query returns 4 records, each record 7 rows) that returns an output like:

```
{HD 208 {} 2012-04-13 25 21 4} {SD 208 {} 2012-04-13 100 97 3} {HD 2072 {} 2012-04-13 5 4 1} {SD 2072 {} 2012-04-13 50 45 6}
```

Now I want to set to store them in a variable and display one by one so that i can display it using html tables
the records are returned in $get_record.
So here's what i am doing

```
foreach record $get_record {
    foreach item [lindex $record 0] {

        set event_name [ lindex $item 0]
        puts $event_name
        set event_date [ lindex $item 1]
        put $event_date
        set attempts_cnt [ lindex $item 2]
        put $attempts_cnt
        set success_cnt [ lindex $item 3]
        put $success_cnt

  }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Tcl 8.5 or greater

```
foreach record $get_record {
    lassign $record event_name event_date attemts_cnt success_cnt
    puts $event_name
    puts $event_date
    puts $attempts_cnt
    puts $success_cnt
}
```

If you have Tcl 8.4 or earlier

```
foreach record $get_record {
    foreach {event_name event_date attemts_cnt success_cnt} $record {break}
    puts $event_name
    puts $event_date
    puts $attempts_cnt
    puts $success_cnt
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the Glenn's answer:

The problem is that you're iterating in a wrong way:

1. In the outer loop, the variable "record" gets assigned each row of the returned rowset, one by one.
2. Then you introduce an inner loop for unknown reason, which works like this:

   1. Extracts the first element from the row contained in the "record" variable;
   2. Interprets that element as a list and iterates over it.  With your data, that element will be something like "HD", which is interpreted as a list of one element ("HD", unsurprisingly).

The mistake should be probably clear now.

Hence the fix offered by Glenn is simple:

- Keep only the outer loop, which iterates over the rows of the resultset.
- For each row, assign the values of that row's "column values" to a set of named variables.  You have been offered idiomatic ways to do that (`lassign` or a trick with `foreach` + `break`) but you could as well just keep your `lindex` + `set` approach (but it's more verbose and less elegant).

Comment: It's not just inelegant and verbose, it's also easier to make silly mistakes when writing it all out by hand. Using the more compact forms is at least as efficient and helps you write things correctly the first time. :-)

Comment: thanks guys..you have been of great help...this is my first attempt at tcl..next I am going to play with tcl arrays..